# omitting last part of a for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop

Are these two peaces of code equivalent ?

```c
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        //some thing
}
```

and

```c
for(int i=0; ++i<10; ){
        //some thing
}
```

if they are the same which one is more standard to use?

Comment: You can also run both these loops and print `i`, see if it does the same thing and whether it does the same amount of steps. I think it won't.

Comment: One is a standard loop from 0 to 9, the other is 1 to 9 I believe. The "I believe" part is the problem. People know how to read the first, the second is not clear. You're writing your code not only for the compiler, also for other people. Stick to the first style unless you have an extremely good reason not to.

Comment: The middle operation (test) is performed before the first loop, but the last part (increment) does not.  So they are different.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't write it as `for(int i = 0; ++i < 10; )`, and `++i` differs from `i++` due to the order of operations. `++i` increments `i` then "returns" it, `i++` "returns" `i` then increments it.

Answer (score 1):

No, these are not the same thing.
You must be aware of the working of prefix increment and postfix increment.

In the second case, in the first iteration of the for loop, variable 'i' will have value 1, but, in the first case the variable 'i' will have value 0 and so on.

Therefore the second loop will run 9 times only whereas the first loop will run 10 times

Answer (score 0):

No its not the same thing but if you write it this way :

`for(int i=0; i<10; ){ //some_thing i++; }`

its the same